# Highcharts - Is it possible to display the my own text on the data-labels of line chart?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Is it possible to **display my own text on the data-labels** of the Line Chart, Only for Non-Zero Entries.
Provided, the text to be displayed in the data-label is passed from an xml along with the data.

I need the chart like the one in the image below.
Please suggest an idea. Thanks for your time.

Highcharts:

```
 xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        if (this.point.y != 0) {
                            return this.point.y;
                        }
                    },
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    backgroundColor: 'pink',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'green',
                    y: -6
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [0, 0,77,120,0,0,150,0,0,0,0]
        }]

}
```

XML:

```
<categories>
    <month>Jan</month>
    <month>Feb</month>
    <month>Mar</month>
    <month>Apr</month>
    <month>May</month>
    <month>Jun</month>
    <month>Jul</month>
    <month>Aug</month>
    <month>Sep</month>
    <month>Oct</month>
    <month>Nov</month>
    <month>Dec</month>
  </categories>
    <Series>
        <point>0|0</point>
        <point>0|0</point>
        <point>120|First</point>
        <point>130|0</point>
        <point>0|0</point>
        <point>0|0</point>
        <point>0|0</point>
        <point>150|Second</point>
        <point>230|Third</point>
        <point>0|0</point>
        <point>0|0</point>
        <point>0|0</point>
      </Series>
```

JQuery:

```
$xml.find('series').each(
                        function(i,series){
                            var ser = {
                                data : [],
                            };
                        $(series).find('point').each(
                                function(i,point){
                                    ser.data.push(parseInt($(point).text().split("|")[0]);
                                });
                        options.series.push(ser);
                        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add extra parameter (text) per each point, which is extracted in the datalabels formatter. In case when datalabel should not be printed for 0 values, add condition which checks that.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataLabels: {
        enabled:true,
      formatter: function() {
        if(this.y > 0)
            return this.point.label;
      }
    }
  }
},
series: [{
  data: [{
    y: 2,
    label: 'text1'
  }, {
    y: 3,
    label: 'text2'
  }, {
    y: 0
  }, {
    y: 4,
    label: 'text3'
  }]
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smfeo9sc/

Comment: Thank you Sebastian! But i am passing the y-axis values through a jquery. I am not sure how to add the data-labels through it.( only that are non-zero) .I Attached my code, in the edited question.